# Mirror rows in excel work sheets VBA not formula

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a excel document that contains 5 sheets,
2018 Bids, Projects Bid, Projects Awarded, Projects Lost, Projects Completed.

Most of my department work is done in 2018 Bids, the other sheets are breakdowns for upper management.

2018 Bids contains all of our projects, Column A contains the "Project Status", 1,2,3 or 4. 1 = Project bid, 2 = Project Awarded, 3 = Project Lost, 4 = Project completed.

Currently I have a code that when I put in a new line item in the "2018 Bids" sheet and assign it a "Project Status" number that line is duplicated in the appropriate worksheet. Great!

Two problems, when the line item is updated in "2018 Bids" it isn't updated in the corresponding worksheet and when that Project Status changes, the line item isn't deleted from the old worksheet (Example. A project moves from "bid" to "Awarded", I update the "Project Status" to a "2", it is still present in "Projects Bid")

The columns within all the sheets are exactly the same.
Looking for a piece of code that would cross check two columns, both "Project Status" & "Customer ID". If a row within in the table on "2018 Bids" contains the same Project Status and Customer ID as a row in "Projects Bid" that row is copied from 2018 bids and pasted on top of the corresponding row in "Projects Bid". If there is a matching Customer ID but the Project Status number doesn't match then that row is deleted. 
Thinking the best way for this to be done would be a button on each worksheet that would update it?...
Sorry if this is confusing, it is way over my head!

Thanks a bunch

Code for copying rows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target.Row > 12 Then
            Dim DestRow As Long
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case 1
                    DestRow = Sheets("Projects Bid").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    Debug.Print Sheets("Projects Bid").Range(Sheets("Projects Bid").Cells(DestRow, "A"), Sheets("Projects Bid").Cells(DestRow, "M")).Address
                    Sheets("Projects Bid").Range(Sheets("Projects Bid").Cells(DestRow, "A"), Sheets("Projects Bid").Cells(DestRow, "M")).Value = Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "M")).Value
                Case 2
                    DestRow = Sheets("Projects Awarded").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    Sheets("Projects Awarded").Range(Sheets("Projects Awarded").Cells(DestRow, "A"), Sheets("Projects Awarded").Cells(DestRow, "M")).Value = Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "M")).Value
                Case 3
                    DestRow = Sheets("Projects Lost").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    Sheets("Projects Lost").Range(Sheets("Projects Lost").Cells(DestRow, "A"), Sheets("Projects Lost").Cells(DestRow, "M")).Value = Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "M")).Value
                Case 4
                    DestRow = Sheets("Projects Completed").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    Sheets("Projects Completed").Range(Sheets("Projects Completed").Cells(DestRow, "A"), Sheets("Projects Completed").Cells(DestRow, "M")).Value = Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "M")).Value
            End Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include the following code, your code is being executed when a cell in your predefined range changes. Just define this range before executing:

```
Sub WorksheetExecute(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("YOUR RANGE")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

Worksheet_Change

End If

End Sub
```

Good luck with it

Comment: Thanks!
Where should I put this code in relation to my other code?

Comment: Your code is already in there. It is called in the third last line.